# how can I use k8s dns name when deploy cnosdb cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cnosdb

In k8s, dns name can be unchangable, the ip is unflexable. the cnosdb github repo provide ip to config the clusters, but in kubernetes the cluster should use dns name, please provide a workaround method to config.

know the best practise to deploy cnosdb in k8s

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the code of the tool you indicate in the question, but not giving the possibility to configure a DNS name in favor of a static IP is generally an anti-pattern, especially on Kubernetes.

However, Network plug-ins like Calico allow you to reserve a static IP address for your Pod.

Take a look here: https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/networking/ipam/use-specific-ip